# Iterate through a filesystem java

Tags: java, filesystems, queue

I have a question regarding iterating through a filesystem tree. Given a queue, and a node to start at, how would you iterate through it? I get that initially, you have to enqueue the node you start with, but I am confused on how to implement the hasNext() and next() methods. Here are the two methods I have to implement, I don't want anybody to give me the code, and if you do, I will just be using it as guidelines,not copying due to plagiarism. Also, recursion is not an option because using it would depth-first traversal rather than the desired breadth-first traversal of the filesystem

```
public boolean hasNext()
public File next()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Queue` implementation. Lets say you start from a node head. First put head in a queue. Iterate over all the children of head and put them in a queue. After all children are done remove head get the next node from queue. This new node will be the head node now. Find it's children and put it in queue and so on... Ad queue follows FIFO (First in First out) you will can implement BFS (Breath first Search) with it.

> and to iterate over all the children in head, would I have to use the listFiles() method, or isDirectory()?

Answering your comment. lets say you have a starting path P1 - head. First check if it is a directory using `isDirectory()` method. If not your traversal is over. If it is do a `listFiles()` on that directory. iterate over the files that `listFiles()` return, do your processing and add it to the queue only if `isDirectory()` is returned true for it. Then pull file from queue and continue processing.

Comment: and to iterate over all the children in head, would I have to use the listFiles() method, or isDirectory(). I know I have to use those methods but don't know when to use which

Comment: @dzagnyr updated the answer to incorporate your comment query.

Comment: thank you! that was very in depth, i appreciate the quick response!